# Camunda7.17 Tables not created on startup

Tags: camunda

Im getting error when starting my springboottest
Caused by:org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ACT_GE_PROPERTY" not found;

Using SpringProcessEngineConfiguration with H2 database. Tried schemaupdate "true" and "create-drop". Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried *create* insteadof *true*?

> camunda.bpm.database.schema-update
>
> If automatic schema update should be applied, use one of [true, false,
> create, create-drop, drop-create]

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/

Comment: tried true, create, create-drop, drop-create. Not working

Comment: Which distro are you using? Please add all config made to the question

Comment: If i dont set databaseTablePrefix, then tables are created and getting multiple times table creation which is another issue.

Comment: I cannot share all configuration. I can give you one by one on the specifics

Comment: Is your normal runtime working? You wrote springboottest. Are you running test with DB? Question really needs more info like how you are bootstrapping then engine with which config. Try to delete the h2 files.

Comment: Removing databaseTablePrefix resolved the issue.